# In Python3, how do you test exception handling within a unit test?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have several unit tests that I'm working on for an api. The tests use @patch to mock the api calls. Some of the tests I wish to create should trigger exceptions. How do I handle that in a unit test?

Here's what I have so far. Pylint complains about the assertTrue() statements. I'm sure there's a better way to handle exceptions.

```
@patch('myapi.myapi.requests.request')
def test_auth_failure(self, mock_request):
    # Configure the request mock to return an auth failure
    # Auth/login (/session) failures return status 200, but without a token!
    mock_request.return_value.status_code = 200
    mock_request.return_value.content = json.dumps(self.mock_auth_failure)
    try:
        # Call auth()
        self.api.auth()
        # Exception should have been raised
        self.assertTrue(False)
    except exceptions.HTTPUnauthorized:
        # Exception caught
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

Additional Information: This is in a class extending from unittest.TestCase. Example:

```
 class MyApiTests(unittest.TestCase):
```

Comment: You missed a `'` in your code, please fix it

Comment: Also is this unittest?

Answer (score 6):

If you're using pytest there's functionality for that...

```
import pytest


def test_zero_division():
    with pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError):
        1 / 0
```

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions

Comment: This is cleaner.  Wish I had more than one vote.

Answer (score 4):

If your class (that defines the *test_auth_failure* method) extends *unittest.TestCase*, you should use [[Python.Docs]: unittest - assertRaises(exception, callable, *args, **kwds)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises):

Replace your ***try*** / ***except*** clause by:

```py
with self.assertRaises(exceptions.HTTPUnauthorized):
    self.api.auth()
```

or

```py
self.assertRaises(exceptions.HTTPUnauthorized, self.api.auth)
```